# How do I access object's values inside of Array in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm working on a React App where I'm passing an array that holds various values for each index and passing it to a prop, but for some reason its not displaying the text inside of my h1. I'm not receiving an error for it, and I've tried researching a bit but I'm unable to find any concrete information.

State:
`var [editTask, setEditTask] = useState([]);`

How I'm writing to the state(works correctly) Keep in mind, im only storing 1 element, this will never have multiple:

```
setEditTask([{
  text: todo.text,
  status: todo.status,
  id: todo.id,
  priority: todo.priority,
}]);
```

How i'm trying to get the text from the array:

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>{props.editTask.id}</h1>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to debug, can you share the complete code React component?

Comment: Get any error? What does the text say?

Comment: No error, and there is no text inside of the h1

Answer (score 0):

Try using the native javascript Object.values() method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing only one element you don't need an array of objects. Can be done with a single object.

```
const [editTask, setEditTask] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  setEditTask({
    ...todo,
  });
}, [todo]);

// Inside component
return (
  <div>
    {Object.values(props.editTask).map((val) => (
      <h1>{val}</h1>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

**Without changing current structure**

```
return (
  <div>{ editTask.map((val) => <h1>{val.status}</h1>)}</div>
);
```

Comment: While this does work(and grabs the entire array) how would I go about just grabbing the singular value from the array, for example, the "status" property from my array I posted above? Is the most efficient way of doing it really making each value a state on their own?

Comment: @一个人在北京  instead of `Object.values` use `<h1>{props.editTask.status}</h1>`.

Comment: @一个人在北京 I've updated my answer do check